# Check if a NumericUpDown has no value

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I check if a user has left a NumericUpDown control empty? I have seen on another question to check the 'Text' property but there is no text property to check against.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check against the `Text` property, although it is hidden from the designer and IntelliSense.

Just try this sample. It does work:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text))
{
    // no value
}
```

Comment: This worked, and thanks for explaining why I couldn't see the Text property in IntelliSense :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ,

```
 if(NumericUpDown.Text == "")
 {
     // If the value in the numeric updown is an empty string, replace with 0.
       NumericUpDown.Text = "0";
 }
```